# Syntax error when trying to CREATE TABLE using session variables

Tags: mysql

The following works in a new MySQL session:

```
CREATE DATABASE rand27818;
USE rand27818;
CREATE TABLE sessions (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, session VARCHAR(128), PRIMARY KEY(id));
DROP DATABASE rand27818;
```

However, this--

```
SET @sesslen = 128;
CREATE DATABASE rand27818;
USE rand27818;
CREATE TABLE sessions (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, session VARCHAR(@sesslen), PRIMARY KEY(id));
DROP DATABASE rand27818;
```

--does not; it returns:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@sesslen), PRIMARY KEY(id))' at line 1"

I've tried several combinations of with extra parentheses around the variable, removing the @ sign, assigning the variable after USEing the database etc. to no joy. (Not that I thought it would make any difference.) Using variables in INSERT statements and SELECTing variables seem to be fine, I'm only encountering a problem trying to CREATE.

I'm thinking this is a curiosity of my installation (MySQL bundled with XAMPP, in case that helps) or me missing something due to a conceptual misunderstanding on my part of MySQL. If the latter, could someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

```
SET @sesslen = 128;
CREATE DATABASE rand27818;
USE rand27818;

SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE sessions (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, session VARCHAR(', @sesslen, '), PRIMARY KEY(id));');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It indeed works, but the example I gave is a snippet from a much larger installation dump I'm writing involving six such variables involved in creating tables with several more fields. As such, prepared statements are overkill--it all begins to get rather unwieldy. Is there really no more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `SET @sesslen := 128;`

You define mysql values with := and not =

Comment: This was not the problem; the variable was being SET anyway. However, I did try this with := and it did not resolve the problem.